# Intermittent Network Instability

Tags: router, troubleshooting, packetloss

I have an office network being run by a Linksys WRT1900AC, and I'm experiencing significant, but intermittent issues. I have between 15 and 20 devices connected to it, including computers, phones, printers, and chrome cast devices.

Upon a restart of the router, everything will work will for a short period of time, but performance will rapidly degrade over time.

Ping tests will start to reveal intermittent packet loss, both to external destinations and to internal destinations (though ping tests to the router itself, for some reason, are always fine, with zero loss). The issue some time ago, but has increased in severity of late.

Where should I start looking?

Comment: It sounds pretty obvious where the problem is.

Comment: Purchase some professional-level equipment and I bet your problems go away.

Comment: The WRT1900AC is a rather highly rated device? Our use of it doesn't truly exceed that use it's designed for....15 devices, especially when over half of them are simply printers and similar devices, doing basic web browsing seems like it ought to be well within the capabilities of this device? I have a far less capable device at home (a buffalo N600), with the same number of devices, with similar use, and have no issues.

Comment: "I have another device which isn't NetGear and it works fine" - yep, so does everyone else. ;)  No, really, have you firmware updated it? Have you seen this [WRT1900AC slowing down](https://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT1900AC-Slowing-down-internet-drastically-Advanced/td-p/878775) thread? Are the slow pings only involving wireless -> x, or also wired->wired? That doesn't have 20 wired sockets, is there a switch involved (what kind?), or all wireless? Have you tried disconnecting some devices then rebooting, repeate with different devices, to see if one is misbehaving?